# Is there any user-mode multi-threading library/framework for C++ under Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I am looking for user-mode multi-threading library/framework for C++ under Linux. I am familiar with boost::thread and ACE_Thread_Manager but AFAIK both of them eventually use OS native thread's support.

Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with native threads. I can't see how you can write "user mode threads" reliably - remember Windows before real threading? Shudder!

Comment: I second the question as to why. You don't gain in a multi-core environment where you can actually have concurrency.

Comment: Neil, Matt, not every use of multithreading is for increasing throughput...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [MTasker](http://ds9a.nl/mtasker/) the kind of thing you're looking for?  It's also a cooperative multi-tasking library.  You might also want to consider just whipping up some state machines.

Also check out [State Threads](http://state-threads.sourceforge.net/) and [MIT Pthreads](http://www.humanfactor.com/pthreads/mit-pthreads.html).

This tool will assist in the generation of hierarchical state machines, which could be used for this purpose: [CHSM](http://chsm.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I've followed your links and it looks interesting (I liked the CHSM). Need more time to puzzle it out. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for CHSM (interesting, even though OT). Boost.StateChart can do similar things (is there anything that's not in Boost? :)

Answer (score 7):

GNU PTH: http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/

It's using cooperative multithreading, which is why it's used in GnuPG (which for security reasons doesn't want real threads, but for responsiveness reasons needs threads).

Comment: "The intention is that this way one can achieve better... run-time performance than with preemptive scheduling" - unless of course your machine has more than one core.

Comment: My machine has once core - actually the application is running on embedded device. All those links provide tons of reading material
(I not complaining). Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @Earwicker: If your throughput demands can be met with a single core, then task switching, cacheline stealing, locking overhead and stuff like that is very likely to make your program run _slower_ with native multithreading than with cooperative, single-thread "multi"threading.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out Intel Thread Building Blocks.  (TBB)

http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

It tries to abstract a lot of the threading concepts away from the programmer while having he/she take more of a task based approach to parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to thread for io type operations you could consider multi-plexing with [select](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

I blogged on this topic a while back: http://yz.mit.edu/wp/cooperative-threads-for-cc/.

At the time I had compared the front-runners State-Threads and GNU Pth, and based on not-too-careful examination of the documentation and code, I walked away with greater confidence in the systems hackery in ST than Pth, but I can't recall the specifics. I've had a positive experience with ST, so never really tried out Pth.

The only thing that worried me about ST is its disclaimer about its (inability to) interop with pthreads.  I had used both in the same project (another reason why Pth probably doesn't fit the bill is that it uses all the same symbol names as pthreads), and I never ran into any issues, but I never stress-tested the combination.

Would be interested in knowing your (and others') experiences WRT these two particular libraries.